# OAuth 2.0 Workflow for Existing Desktop Application

Tags: wpf, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I'm tasked with updating an existing WPF application to support OIDC to an Okta instance.  I plan on keeping this IdP-independent, so I'm not using Okta's SSO libraries.

The desktop application retrieves an authorization key (which is just an encrypted forms auth ticket), and we use this to generate tokens for use on the API.  We'd like to avoid changing how this works at the moment, going for MVP.

My first stab at this took using [IdentityModel.OidcClient](https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient).  Using manual mode, I launch the browser and get the identity back from Okta as expected.  Unfortunately, my application is expecting a user from our sytsem, not an OIDC user.

At this point, I could send the access token to the server, validate it, and then use our current method to generate an authorization key to return so the desktop has minimal changes.

But at this point, does it even make sense for the desktop to even make the call itself to Okta?

One proposal was still launching the browser, but having our website (the one that backs the desktop client) perform the challenge to Okta.  This site is also going to be supporting OIDC to Okta as well.  The site would then receive the callback.  In that callback endpoint, we can verify the user, and then generate an authorization key (the one we use already in the desktop client). Then do a redirect to localhost (just like we do with the OIDC client in my first stab), and get the authorization key through the query string.

Is this the wrong approach?

Not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend trying to head the architecture in a standard direction as much as possible, and thinking how it would look with the best separation of Desktop / API / Web concerns:

- Desktop app manages sign in via the system browser
- The response returned to the browser is a (short lived one time use) authorization code and not any form of access token - it is recommended to avoid returning access tokens directly to the browser, to protect against interception or possibly including tokens in the browser history
- The desktop app itself swaps the code for tokens
- An API serves both the Desktop and Web apps and uses access tokens as the message credential
- The browser UI for the web app may possibly use a 'Back End for Front End' that involves translating from auth cookies to access tokens. This should ultimately result in the browser getting data via the same API as the desktop app.

With this type of setup each component does OAuth in the standard way and is easy to understand. Once built, your apps will have the best future options and will also do well in security reviews.

It is common for systems to have a 'web back end' that is too focused on web clients, and that works less well for mobile / desktop apps. It is sometimes necessary to refactor the web back end into new API entry points or microservices that use access tokens and work equivalently for all types of client. This can be done gradually though, so you may only do a Stage 1 for your MVP.